# PHP mktime hell

Tags: php, date, mktime

I have a function that calculate the days difference between two dates:

```
function daysBetweenDates($startDate, $endDate) {
  list($year1, $month1, $day1) = explode('-', $startDate);
  list($year2, $month2, $day2) = explode('-', $endDate);
  $f = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month2, $day2, $year2);
  $i = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month1, $day1, $year1);
  $difference =  $f - $i;
  $days = floor($difference/86400);
  return $days;
}
```

The problem is that this code is getting weird results with some dates. For example if the `$startDate = '2014-10-14'` and `$endDate = '2014-10-28'`, the output of this function everywhere is `14`, but i am getting `13`.
I have checked some online php interpreters and for some goddamn reason i don't know why, my `mktime` is returning me different values.

Example:

on `3v4l.org` running `mktime(0, 0, 0, 10, 28, 2014)` returns `1414450800` for `PHP versions 5.1.0 - 5.5.8`
on `3v4l.org` running `mktime(0, 0, 0, 10, 14, 2014)` returns `1413237600` for `PHP versions 5.1.0 - 5.5.8`
The output of the function with these values is `14`.

In my code, when i run the same values on `mktime` i get `1414461600` and `1413255600` respectively. Running this code the output of the function is `13`.

And i am running on `PHP 5.3.3`.

Any help on understanding what is wrong with my environment/php configuration/function error/bad code will be great appreciated.

Comment: Is there a daylight savings shift between your dates in the default timezone setting that's defined in your php.ini file?

Comment: The difference between those two timestamps is 13 days 23 hours. So there must be a DST change.

Comment: Try using `round()` instead of `floor()`.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it is the DST change.

Comment: And @Glavić, i am not asking HOW to calculate, i am demonstrating a problem with my code. So read the question before voting for a close.

Comment: @MurifoX: if you are even considering vascowhite's answer, then my vote was correct, because then it is duplicate...

Comment: @MurifoX: like I said, duplicate ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using DateTime rather than mktime will end your hell:-

```
function daysBetweenDates($startDate, $endDate) {
  $startDate = new \DateTime($startDate);
  $endDate = new \DateTime($endDate);
  return $startDate->diff($endDate)->days;
}
```

Should get you close to what you need. It will take into account any DST changes under the hood, which is probably your issue as DST (in UK anyway) ends on 26th October this year.

For your example dates, this returns [14](http://3v4l.org/jfOB6)

Reference http://php.net/datetime

Comment: Well, i think the problem has something to do with DST. Will give a try with your answer.

Comment: @MurifoX Yes, I explain that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `mktime` is based on your current timezone. The values you give to `mktime` are "wall clock time", it returns an absolute point-in-human-history UNIX timestamp. For this it needs to consider your current timezone, set by `date_default_timezone_set`. If there's a DST transition in between these two times, there may be an hour more or less between these two *wall clock times* than in other timezones. Therefore, a day is not guaranteed to be exactly 86400 seconds long, and you're stumbling across this problem here. In short: this is too naïve a way of doing time difference calculations, because you're ignoring all the factors that make human times so messy. See @vascowhite's answer for how to use the existing libraries that do take all that into account.

Answer (score 0):

Return of function `mktime()` is based on current timezone set.

If you wish to return timestamp for GMT date, then just use function [`gmmktime()`](http://php.net/manual/function.gmmktime.php).

Or, you can set parameter `$is_dst` in function `mktime()` to `0`, which means that DST is ignored.